iOS用にビルドする際にエラーが発生する
UnityのiOS用にビルドしたいのですが、以下のようなエラー文が表示されます。
Unityを始めて日が浅い為どのように解決すればいいのかわかりません。どなたかわかる方はいらっしゃいませんか？
・ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEditor is referenced by CapsuleGizmo ('Assets/Vector Field/Scripts/CapsuleGizmo.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

・UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)


もうちょっと詳しく、Unity でどのような手順でビルドを行ったかを記載いただくと、回答を得られるかもしれません。
